# Trouble with my Sublime text editor

Tags: html

I have put the following code into my sublime 3 text editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>All about rabbits!!</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>All about rabbits!</h1>

    <h2>Basic info</h2>

    <h2>Songs</h2>

    </body>
</html>
```

I would like it to out put:

"All about rabbits

basic info

songs"

But I am only getting a page that returns the code word for word.  I think there is a problem with sublime reading my code.

Comment: does the file end with `.html`? if not, it'll just display plaintext. also, sublime isn't responsible for reading your code, that's the browser

Comment: If you drag the .html file to a browser window, what happens? Does it display in the manner you expect?